# Jquery dialog: content shown before the dialog is open

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-dialog

I have some HTML code with a dialog inside, like this:

```
<center>
<a href="#add_auto" id="add_auto" onclick="addAuto();" >
    <img " src="/css/images/add_author_automated.png"; id="add_author_automated"; alt="-"; />
</a>
</center>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" >
    <textarea style="width: 95%; heigth: 400px" name="authors-auto-adding"; id="authors-auto-adding"></textarea>
    <input text-align="center" type="BUTTON" onclick="processAuthorsParagraph();" value="Process";  />
</div>
```

When the image is clicked, I am callig the function addAuto:

```
function addAuto()
{
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 300,
        width: 800,
        modal: true
    });
}
```

But the problem is that the first time the page is opened, I have the dialog content in on the main page. When I open the dialog and then close, the dilog content disapears from the main page.

I have try to use

```
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
```

in the document.ready but nothing changes.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `style="display: none"` in the tags of the `<div>`

When the dialog is shown the style will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If you add this line to your CSS it will work wonders:

```css
#dialog-modal { display: none; }
```

This will make your modal be hidden by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can put display:none directly into the html markup of the div element of wrapper for the dailog

```
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display:none;" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. I had the same problem. The solution is very easy: do not print it in your HTML code, but wrap it in Javascrip as well...

```
var your_dialog_html = $('<div>your html code here, but attention: without new lines! in your editor</div>')
var your_dialog = $( your_dialog_html ).dialog({
         /* options here */
});

$('#trigger').click(function() {    
    your_dialog.dialog('open');
    return false; // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea in this case. CSS is there to serve. Putting HTML to Javascript code is a terrible thing, even more if it's long HTML.

Comment: @Alnitak: hey, sorry Alnitak - yes, you are right your solution is more elegant and thank you I have learned from this as well - but I found your comment "a snippet of unrelated code" and "it does not help" honestly unnecessarily offensive and incorrect, because my code is related and actually works...

Comment: @Chris I don't think it was offensive. Most of the code is unrelated to what you actually want to show. And we don't know if it works, because there is no demo.

Comment: @Chris my point was you could have just said `$.dialog({...})` and omitted the code that's specific to _your_ use.  It would avoid confusion for those coming later and trying to figure out why your dialog code is different to the OP's.  And the reason is - that part of the code unrelated to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );`, but there is no #dialog in your markup.

Sidestepping this fact, to solve your problem I would set #dialog-modal to `display: none;` via CSS.  You can then use `$.fn.show()` or `display: block;` on the dialog's `open` callback.  This will not show the content until it is present in the dialog.

Comment: jQuery UI will automatically `show` the dialog when it's first opened.